# All tangled up in IF and ELIF and TRY

Tags: python

I'm working on a small program to add or remove certain entries from the Windows registry, and I'm getting all tangled up in IF and TRY conditions. I've spent hours chasing bugs, usually logical ones, trying to accomplish what is conceptually very simple. The more I work on and "improve" the code so that it works in more and more conditions, the more tortured and complicated the IF tests get, until I can't tell which is up and down anymore. Surely there must be a better way! (even for my little brain)

This is all I'm trying to do:

When asked to install:

If our python version and installpath is in registry: do nothing.
If our python version and different installpath: do nothing.
If our python is not there, add it.

When asked to remove:

If our python is not there: do nothing
If our python version and different installpath: do nothing.
If our python version and installpath is in registry: remove.

But my code for just the removal part looks like the below (the [whole thing is here](http://code.google.com/p/maphew/source/browse/register-python/register-python.py)). It works, more or less, but it just doesn't feel right. I don't know what to do to make it cleaner. Your viewpoints are appreciated. Thanks.

```
def remove():
    ''' see if any existing registrations match our python version and register ours if not '''

    if CurrentUser:
        match = True if our_version in CurrentUser else False
        versions = CurrentUser
    elif AllUsers:
        match = True if our_version in AllUsers else False
        versions = AllUsers
    else:
        print '\nOur version (%s) not registered to "%s", skipping...' % (our_version, versions[our_version])

    try:
        if match:
            print '\nVersion matches ours, calling deRegisterPy...'
            deRegisterPy(pycore_regpath,our_version)
    except:
        raise

def deRegisterPy(pycore_regpath, version):
    ''' remove this python install from registry '''
    pycore_regpath = pycore_regpath + version   # e.g. 'SOFTWARE\Python\Pythoncore\2.7'
    try:
        reg = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pycore_regpath)
        installpath = QueryValue(reg, installkey) # win32
        if installpath == our_installpath:
            print '\nexisting python matches ours, removing...\n'
            # print '(%s vs %s)' % (installpath, our_installpath)
            for subkey in ['\\InstallPath', '\\PythonPath']:
                DeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pycore_regpath + subkey)
            DeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pycore_regpath)
            print "--- Python %s, %s is now removed!" % (our_version, our_installpath)
        CloseKey(reg)
    except EnvironmentError:
        print 'EnvironmentError', EnvironmentError()
        raise
        return
    except WindowsError:
        print "Strange, we've hit an exception, perhaps the following will say why:"
        print WindowsError()
        raise
        return
    CloseKey(reg)

# main
if args['action']=='install':
    install()
elif args['action']=='remove':
    remove()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def remove():
    ''' see if any existing registrations match our python version and register ours if not '''

    if CurrentUser:
```

The python style guide reserves CamelCase for class names. If this is a global constant it should be CURRENT_USER. If its not a global constant, it shouldn't be accessed as a global variable.

```
        match = True if our_version in CurrentUser else False
```

Just use `match = our_version in CurrentUser`

```
        versions = CurrentUser
    elif AllUsers:
        match = True if our_version in AllUsers else False
        versions = AllUsers



    else:
        print '\nOur version (%s) not registered to "%s", skipping...' % (our_version, versions[our_version])

    try:
        if match:
            print '\nVersion matches ours, calling deRegisterPy...'
            deRegisterPy(pycore_regpath,our_version)
    except:
        raise
```

What??? the try..except does nothing if you just raise the error right away

```
def deRegisterPy(pycore_regpath, version):
```

Python style guide recommends lower_case_with_underscores for functions names

```
    ''' remove this python install from registry '''
    pycore_regpath = pycore_regpath + version   # e.g. 'SOFTWARE\Python\Pythoncore\2.7'
    try:
        reg = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pycore_regpath)
        installpath = QueryValue(reg, installkey) # win32
```

Why are you taking the time to point out that its win32 here?

```
        if installpath == our_installpath:
            print '\nexisting python matches ours, removing...\n'
            # print '(%s vs %s)' % (installpath, our_installpath)
```

Don't leave dead code in comments

```
            for subkey in ['\\InstallPath', '\\PythonPath']:
                DeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pycore_regpath + subkey)
            DeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pycore_regpath)
            print "--- Python %s, %s is now removed!" % (our_version, our_installpath)
        CloseKey(reg)
    except EnvironmentError:
        print 'EnvironmentError', EnvironmentError()
```

What are you trying to do here? You construct a new EnviromentError object, and then print it. But that's a pointless thing to do

```
        raise
```

If you are just going to raise the error again, not a whole lot of point in printing it anyways
            return

Do you realize that nothing after the raise will be executed, so this return will have no effect?

```
    except WindowsError:
        print "Strange, we've hit an exception, perhaps the following will say why:"
        print WindowsError()
```

You seem to be confused about how to catch errors, you want:

```
except WindowsError as error:
    print error
```

But really you don't need to do that: just let the exceptions fly and python will print them when it exits due to the error

```
        raise
        return
```

Again, the return will never be reached

```
    CloseKey(reg)
```

If an exception occurs, this will never be called. You should put it in a finally block or something

```
# main
if args['action']=='install':
    install()
elif args['action']=='remove':
    remove()
```

You should really put logic like this in a main function.

Any my rewrite of your whole linked file. No testing has been done. But it should give you something of an idea of what you can do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from _winreg import *

import argparse, sys
import os.path

PYTHON_VERSION = "%d.%d" % sys.version_info[0:2]

# the registry key paths we'll be looking at & using
PYCORE_REGISTRY_PATH = ("SOFTWARE","Python","Pythoncore")
INSTALL_KEY = "InstallPath"
PYTHON_KEY = "PythonPath"
PYTHONPATH = ";".join( os.path.join(sys.prefix, sub) for sub in ["", "Lib", "DLLs"])

class RegisteryKeyNotFound(Exception):
    pass

class RegisteryKey(object):
    def __init__(self, hive):
        self._key = key

    def _path_from(self, segments):
        if not isinstance(segments, tuple):
            segments = (segments,)

        return "\\".join(segments)

    def __getitem__(self, segments):
        try:
            subkey = _winreg.OpenKey(self._key, self._path_from(segments))
        except WindowsError:
            # should really check the error
            # to make sure that key not found is the real problem
            raise RegisteryKeyNotFound(path)
        return RegisteryKey(subkey)

    def get_or_create(self, segments):
        subkey = _winreg.CreateKey(self._key, self._path_from(segments))
        return RegisteryKey(subkey)


    def value(self, segments):
        return _winreg.QueryValue(self._key, self._path_from(segments))

    def delete(self, segments):
        _winreg.DeleteKey(self._key, self._path_from(segments))

    def set_value(self, segments, value):
        _winreg.SetValue(self._key, self._path_from(segments), REG_SZ, value)

    def __iter__(self):
        index = 0
        while True:
            try:
                yield RegisteryKey(EnumKey(key, index))
            except WindowsError:
                # add check to make sure correct here was gotten
                break
            else:
                index += 1

    def __del__(self):
        _winreg.CloseKey(self._key)

HIVE_LOCAL_MACHINE = RegisteryKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
HIVE_CURRENT_USER = RegisteryKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER)

def get_existing(hive):
    ''' retrieve existing python registrations '''

    try:
        key = hive[PYCORE_REGISTRY_PATH]
    except RegisteryKeyNotFound:
        return {}

    versions = {}
    for version in key:
        versions[version] = version.value(INSTALL_KEY)                           # e.g. {'2.7' = 'C:\\Python27'}

    return versions

def register_python(version):
    ''' put this python install into registry '''
    try:
        reg = HIVE_LOCAL_MACHINE[PYCORE_REGISTRY_PATH][version]
    except RegisteryKeyNotFound:
        reg = HIVE_LOCAL_MACHINE.get_or_create(PYCORE_REGISTRY_PATH).get_or_create(version)
        reg.set_value(INSTALL_KEY, sys.prefix)
        reg.set_value(PYTHON_KEY, PYTHONPATH)
        print "--- Python %s is now registered to %s!" % (PYTHON_VERSION, sys.prefix)
    else:
        print reg.value(INSTALL_KEY)

    if reg.value(INSTALL_KEY) == sys.prefix and reg.value(PYTHON_KEY) == PYTHONPATH:
        print "=== Python %s is already registered!" % (PYTHON_VERSION)
    else:
        print "*** Unable to register!"
        print "*** You probably have another Python installation!"

def deregister_python(version):
    ''' remove this python install from registry '''
    reg = HIVE_LOCAL_MACHINE[PYCORE_REGISTRY_PATH][version]
    install_path = reg.value(INSTALL_KEY)
    if install_path == sys.prefix:
        print '\nexisting python matches ours, removing...\n'
        for subkey in ['InstallPath', 'PythonPath']:
            reg.delete(subkey)
        reg.delete()
        print "--- Python %s, %s is now removed!" % (PYTHON_VERSION, sys.prefix)

def install(installed_versions):
    ''' see if any existing registrations match our python version, and if not, register ours '''

    print '\n...installing'

    if PYTHON_VERSION in installed_versions:
        print '\nOur version (%s) already registered to "%s", skipping...' % (PYTHON_VERSION, installed_versions[PYTHON_VERSION])
    else:
        print '\nPutting python from environment into registry...\n'
        register_python()

def remove(installed_versions):
    ''' see if any existing registrations match our python version and register ours if not '''
    #print args
    if PYTHON_VERSION in installed_versions:
        deregister_python()
    else:
        print '\nOur version (%s) not registered, skipping...' % (PYTHON_VERSION)



# @url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042452/display-help-message-with-python-argparse-when-script-is-called-without-any-argum
# display the usage message when it is called with no arguments
class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        sys.stderr.write('error: %s\n' % message)
        self.print_help()
        sys.exit(2)



def main():
    parser=MyParser()
    parser.add_argument('action', help='one of "install" or "remove" ')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    current_user_versions = get_existing(HIVE_CURRENT_USER)
    local_machine_versions = get_existing(HIVE_LOCAL_MACHINE)

    print '\nFound in Current User:'
    for key, value in current_user_versions.items():
        print "\t%s - %s" % (key, value)
    print '\nFound in All Users:'
    for key, value in local_machine_version.items():
        print "\t%s - %s" % (key, value)

    all_versions = {}
    all_versions.update(current_user_versions)
    all_versions.update(local_machine_versions)


    if args.action == 'install':
        install(all_versions)
    elif args.action == 'remove':
        remove(all_versions)
    else:
        print '\nInvalid action specified. I only understand "install" and "remove". '

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Some notes:

1. The _winreg interface is rather low level. You can make code a lot clearer by wrapping it in something more pythonic. I've only taken a first stab at an interface, and it probably could be done a lot better.
2. You split out CurrentUser and LocalMachine but treated them pretty much exactly the same. The code can be simplified by merging them into a giant dictionary of versions
3. you remove python from LocalMachine but not CURRENT_USER. That seems odd but I've not changed it.

Comment: Small typo but the first line of `def main():` needs an extra space.

Comment: Winston thank you for your advice. I'm sure it took some time. I'll leave more feedback after I've properly digested your advice.

Comment: after reading through your example several times I finally "get" classes in a way I didn't previously. It helps seeing it applied to something I'm familiar with. Thank you.

Comment: re #3, that's a mistake. It supposed to remove from whichever one of LocalMachine or CurrentUser has the python of interest registered.

Comment: I committed your version as [classy-reggie.py](http://code.google.com/p/maphew/source/browse/register-python/classy-reggie.py), but haven't been able to get it to work yet. It fails with `Exception NameError: "global name '_winreg' is not defined"` (there's more, just not enough room in comment to put it).

Comment: "You seem to be confused about how to catch errors..." yup! though now the fog is parting some. And no I didn't realise nothing after raise is touched.

Comment: @mattwilkie, I put little thought into that class. I'd actually go see if someone has written a wrapper on python registry settings that you could use. The error you mention will be because you haven't imported _winreg. You imported everything inside it with `from _winreg import *` but I prefer to use `import _winreg` and explicitly refer to `_winreg.function`. I make no guarantees that the code will work at all.

Comment: @mattwilkie, I also don't know the windows registry well enough to do a really good job at it. There seemed to be an odd duality between keys and values and I'm not sure the best way of handling that. If I were to pursue your project more fully I'd start by researching. Starting with my piece of code may not be the best since its had not testing whatesover. I intended it to show an example, not be a good starting point.

Comment: changing to straight `import _winreg` fixed the err mentioned, but that minor problem was masking a bigger one in the `__init__` part of `class RegisteryKey`. I *think* it's supposed to be `self._key = hive` instead of `self._key = key`, at least making that change gets us farther down the line of execution before failing with `TypeError: The object is not a PyHKEY object`.  I have done a fair bit of searching to locate a windows registry wrapper but came up empty; could be I'm just not using the right language.

Comment: I do appreciate that it's not the reviewers' job to come up with tested, complete alternatives to the problems present. That the focus is on presenting alternate ways of thinking about the challenges, and directions for further research and exploration. It's just hard from the ignorant side of the veil to discriminate between errors which are of the typo variety (e.g. *import x* instead of *from x import*) and those that may be from an actual flaw in understanding the problem or the solution pattern being presented. In any case I thank you much for what you've done to improve my understanding.

Comment: @mattwilkie, glad to help. I'm surprised that nobody has created a useful wrapper of the windows registry. You are correct about the key/hive but I'm not sure why it didn't give you a NameError about that. At any rate, you may find it easier to create a new registry wrapping class then trying to fix my hack job.

Comment: @mattwilkie, truth be told I constantly put down the wrong variable name when I write code. I catch this when I test my code, but you trying to untangle that may not be worth your effort.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1608/discussion-between-matt-wilkie-and-winston-ewert)